# How to define a function in python language?

Tags: python

In this code, identify the repeated pattern and replace it with a function called month_days, that receives the name of the month and the number of days in that month as parameters. Adapt the rest of the code so that the result is the same. Confirm your results by making a function call with the correct parameters for both months listed.

```
# REPLACE THIS STARTER CODE WITH YOUR FUNCTION
june_days = 30
print("June has " + str(number) + " days.")
july_days = 31
print("July has " + str(number) + " days.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour (stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the help center (stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to try to create a function.  There are hundreds of examples of how to define functions in Python questions on StackOverlow.  Then come back you have specific problems.

Answer (score 3):

It is rather difficult to understand your problem precisely, but I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
def month_days(month, days):
    result = f"{month} has {days} days."
    return (result)
print (month_days("June", 30))
print (month_days("July", 31))
```

Comment: If you're unsure of what the OP is trying to achieve due to a lack of details/clarity you should comment to ask for updates. If you lack the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) required to do so then look for clearly defined questions you can answer or ask your own questions in order to gain rep.

Comment: Thanks! Still new here. Was just trying to help.